# Windows 2008 R2 Domain users can't change keyboard layout

Tags: windows

We have a group of students that need to be able to switch keyboard layout in order to complete coursework (Chinese, but this really applies to any layout).

All of these students share a single mandatory profile and this profile has been updated with the correct registry settings to set up the keyboard layouts available to the student. Students can now see the Language Bar and can see the various keyboard options.

When a student selects one of the various options, the Language Bar visually updates to indicate the language has been changed, but no related tools for the selected language appear and the input language remains in English.

What are we missing? Is there something we need to toggle in Group Policy for these students?

Update: the machines in question are all running Windows 7, and we are running a Server 2008 R2 domain.

Update 2: Teachers are able to switch keyboard layouts without a problem, it's only students (who are highly restricted users) that have trouble with this. I'm not sure what could be causing this issue though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Languages also must be available locally.

Comment: This makes sense, but what is the process for this? The Chinese (Simplified) Language Pack for example is only available via Windows Update (but not WSUS).

Comment: You should be able to add any language locally via control panel. I am not sure if you can do it GP from AD.

Comment: This ended up being the issue - also needed to update the mandatory profile these users have in order to get this to work.